# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout . I can not find any answer for this error

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

### This is the Data model

```
  package com.basirahmad.qpaisa.data_model;

  public class Banner_data_model {

    private String banner_url_com_logo;
    private String banner_txt_title;
    private String banner_txt_name;
    private String banner_txt_description;
    private String banner_url_banner;
    private String banner_date_publish;
    private String banner_date_expire;
    private String banner_max_view;
    private int banner_com_id;
    private int banner_schedual_id;
    private int banner_id;

    public String getBanner_url_com_logo() {
        return banner_url_com_logo;
    }

    public void setBanner_url_com_logo(String banner_url_com_logo) {
        this.banner_url_com_logo = banner_url_com_logo;
    }

    public String getBanner_txt_title() {
        return banner_txt_title;
    }

    public void setBanner_txt_title(String banner_txt_title) {
        this.banner_txt_title = banner_txt_title;
    }

    public String getBanner_txt_name() {
        return banner_txt_name;
    }

    public void setBanner_txt_name(String banner_txt_name) {
        this.banner_txt_name = banner_txt_name;
    }

    public String getBanner_txt_description() {
        return banner_txt_description;
    }

    public void setBanner_txt_description(String banner_txt_description) {
        this.banner_txt_description = banner_txt_description;
    }

    public String getBanner_url_banner() {
        return banner_url_banner;
    }

    public void setBanner_url_banner(String banner_url_banner) {
        this.banner_url_banner = banner_url_banner;
    }

    public String getBanner_date_publish() {
        return banner_date_publish;
    }

    public void setBanner_date_publish(String banner_date_publish) {
        this.banner_date_publish = banner_date_publish;
    }

    public String getBanner_date_expire() {
        return banner_date_expire;
    }

    public void setBanner_date_expire(String banner_date_expire) {
        this.banner_date_expire = banner_date_expire;
    }

    public String getBanner_max_view() {
        return banner_max_view;
    }

    public void setBanner_max_view(String banner_max_view) {
        this.banner_max_view = banner_max_view;
    }

    public int getBanner_com_id() {
        return banner_com_id;
    }

    public void setBanner_com_id(int banner_com_id) {
        this.banner_com_id = banner_com_id;
    }

    public int getBanner_schedual_id() {
        return banner_schedual_id;
    }

    public void setBanner_schedual_id(int banner_schedual_id) {
        this.banner_schedual_id = banner_schedual_id;
    }

    public int getBanner_id() {
        return banner_id;
    }

    public void setBanner_id(int banner_id) {
        this.banner_id = banner_id;
    }
}
```

### This is the Adapter Class

```
package com.basirahmad.qpaisa.adapter;

public class Banner_adapter_con extend

 RecyclerView.Adapter<Banner_adapter_con.BannerViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Banner_data_model> banner_data_models;

    //the class canstractor;
    public Banner_adapter_con(Context context, List<Banner_data_model>banner_data_models ){

        this.context = context;
        this.banner_data_models = banner_data_models;
    }

    @Override
    public BannerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.banner_view,parent,false);
        return new BannerViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BannerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Banner_data_model data_model = banner_data_models.get(position);
        holder.company_logo.setImageURI(Uri.parse(data_model.getBanner_url_com_logo()));
        holder.title.setText(data_model.getBanner_txt_title());
        holder.name.setText(data_model.getBanner_txt_name());
        holder.description.setText(data_model.getBanner_txt_description());
        holder.banner.setImageURI(Uri.parse(data_model.getBanner_url_banner()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return banner_data_models.size();
    }

    public class BannerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private ImageView company_logo;
        private ImageView banner;
        private TextView title;
        private TextView name;
        private ReadMoreTextView description;
        public BannerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            company_logo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_company_logo);
            banner = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_banner);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.banner_txt_title);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.banner_txt_name);
            description = (ReadMoreTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.banner_txt_description);
        }
    }
}
```

### This is the Fragment Class

package com.basirahmad.qpaisa.Fragment;

```
public class Banner_fragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.banner_fragment,container,false);
        Banner_data_server banner_data_server = new Banner_data_server(this.getActivity());
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.banner_fragment);
        banner_data_server.getBanner(new Banner_data_server.OnbannerRecevid() {
            @Override
            public void onRecevid(List<Banner_data_model> banner_data_models) {
                Banner_adapter banner_adapter =new Banner_adapter(getActivity(),banner_data_models);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(banner_adapter);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It will not throw any error. It just means when you initialized your `RecyclerView` you've not set its adapter,

IF you still want to remove this warning, you can call

```
recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter)
```

just after its initialization. will remove the warning.

Answer (score 0):

**how derar this is the class the get data from server i forgot this class to add to the quastion.**

```
enter code here the class code

package com.basirahmad.qpaisa.connect_to_server;




public class Banner_data_server {

private Context context;

public Banner_data_server(Context context){

    this.context = context;
}

public void getBanner(final OnbannerRecevid onbannerRecevid){

    JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url_of_server.urlReadBanner, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            List<Banner_data_model> banner_data_models = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i =0;i<response.length();i++){
                Banner_data_model data_model = new Banner_data_model();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject =response.getJSONObject(i);
                    data_model.setBanner_id(jsonObject.getInt("Banner_id"));
                    data_model.setBanner_txt_name(jsonObject.getString("Banner_name"));
                    data_model.setBanner_txt_description(jsonObject.getString("Banner_description"));
                    data_model.setBanner_url_banner(jsonObject.getString("location"));
                    data_model.setBanner_schedual_id(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                    data_model.setBanner_date_publish(jsonObject.getString("date_publish"));
                    data_model.setBanner_date_expire(jsonObject.getString("expire_date"));
                    data_model.setBanner_com_id(jsonObject.getInt("com_id"));
                    data_model.setBanner_url_com_logo(jsonObject.getString("logo"));
                    banner_data_models.add(data_model);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            onbannerRecevid.onRecevid(banner_data_models);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    arrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(18000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(arrayRequest);



}
  public interface OnbannerRecevid{
    void onRecevid(List<Banner_data_model> banner_data_models);
```

}

}